# Background independent string theory

Tags: string-theory, sigma-models

I don't really understand what one actually means when one says about doing string theory in a background independent way.

Apparently B. Sathiapalan is the only person (as far as I know from literature searching) who has been looking into it from a long time. Here is a very recent [review](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03692) by Sathiapalan. The introduction and conclusions of it look very nicely written.

What is background dependence in string theory and what must a background independent theory fulfill?

Comment: Sorry for the close vote,but I feel your question is too broad for this  Q and A setup, it's not really the place due to space limitations, for a discussion forum. On the good  side though, I think CuriousOne has given a succinct reply to your title question.

Comment: @AcidJazz I thought this *is* the place to discuss or to understand unknown concepts/progress of physics and also I don't understand why you are saying this "question is too broad". Anyway I have already imported this question to PO..

Comment: @pinu hi, the reason I know it's not a discussion forum is because I wrote a post, pretty much like yours, and it was closed as discussion based. I was told the site was designed for one or two related concepts in a Q and A format only.  Also _can someone discuss in detail where...independence occur in string theory and the progress so far in this direction._ is a fairly broad, in my opinion, remit. On the good side, I hope, I up voted your question yesterday, because I am interested in it & to increase the chance of another closure opinion or answer. I hope you do get an answer, seriously

Comment: I don't think this question is too broad, it is just unluckily worded. Instead of asking for a "discussion", why not just pose the question as "What is background dependence in string theory and what must a background independent theory fulfill?"?

Comment: I understand the situation. It's all due to bad choice of words! :) Edited.

Comment: "ACuriosmind", Loop Quantum Gravity is a background independent theory which attempts to unify General Relativity and Quantum Mechanics: it's not a toy model and it's mathematically well defined.